# With GSCopyPurpleNamedPort(appId) in GraphicsServices deprecated in IOS7, what is the alternative approach?

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi, ios7

I want to send gsevent in IOS7. Which I follow from here:[How to find the purple port for the front most application in IOS 5 and above?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156831/how-to-find-the-purple-port-for-the-front-most-application-in-ios-5-and-above/16157532#16157532)

I got it working for IOS 4,5,6, now I am working on IOS7 beta. I found out that the private API has been changed. The result of GSCopyPurpleNamedPort(appId) is always 0.

So how do I get the purple port of the current running application for IOS7, anyone has any ideas?

Comment: This question brushed into NDA based SDKs. The OP is not allowed to discuss iOS 7.

Comment: @NilsMunch It's up to the OP and any answerers to honour the NDA, it isn't for SO to enforce.

Comment: @Abizern Fair enough :)

Comment: @NilsMunch Not that it isn't a question for closure, but not for reasons of NDA alone. :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in the console logs, whether it says anything.

Most likely (it's a guess), they protected it with some entitlement and since your application doesn't have it, you will get 0 as result.

Comment: Sadly the console didn't say anything. Although GSGetPurpleSystemEventPort() this is still working. And if I try to send gsevent to system purple port, the console will give some errors. I will post the error msg next time when I tried it.

Comment: i m getting the console logs, as victor said, it says that it has been protected

Comment: @ Victor Ronin did you get a solution PLZ ?

Comment: @HDNZ: I didn't touch private API's already for about 8-9 month. It looks like iOS 8 became even more string with private API's and protected a lot of them with entitlements, so this area is become almost dead.