# Simulate touch on ios7/8

Tags: objective-c, ios7, touch, simulate

I want to simulate a touch on iOS7/8, I googled and I found that the API are changed from iOS6 to iOS 7 and I should use the  IOHIDEvent (in IOKit.framework) for touch events but I didn't get a good example to start PLZ if anybody have an idea to begin give me how to do it .

Comment: You could begin by reading this : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/Introduction/Introduction.html, the official documentation. And this : http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/iokit-an-introduction/ , good tutorial :)

Comment: What do you mean "simulate a touch". Can't you do that on a higher level? What I mean is instead of "simulating a touch" can't you call a method that executes the underlying action? I don't quite understand the question though ... Maybe you can elaborate a little bit on what you goal is.

Comment: This tuto http://blog.lazerwalker.com/blog/2013/10/16/faking-touch-events-on-ios-for-fun-and-profit talk about what I want but it's for iOS6 so I search for another alternative to do it.I hope that it's more clear and u can help me to do it